How to form 3X3 grid dynamically in CSS bootstrap?
I want to place 8 checkboxes into 3X3 grid. Checkboxes are visible only on certain conditions and so I need to fill grid dynamically. How it can be done with CSS and bootstrap? Checkboxes to be put in grid from top to bottom and left to right. I don't want any space in grid if checkbox is not visible.
Following is my code for STATIC arrangement.
<div class="row row-checkbox">
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <app-custom-checkbox formControlName="cb1" label="Checkbox1">
              </app-custom-checkbox>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <app-custom-checkbox formControlName="cb2" label="Checkbox 2">
              </app-custom-checkbox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <app-custom-checkbox formControlName="cb3" label="Checkbox 3">
              </app-custom-checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row row-checkbox">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <app-custom-checkbox formControlName="cb4" label="Checkbox 4">
              </app-custom-checkbox>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <app-custom-checkbox formControlName="cb5" label="Checkbox 5">
              </app-custom-checkbox>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <app-custom-checkbox formControlName="cb6" label="Checkbox 6">
              </app-custom-checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row row-checkbox">
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <app-custom-checkbox formControlName="cb7" label="Checkbox 7">
              </app-custom-checkbox>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-4">
              <app-custom-checkbox formControlName="cb8" label="Checkbox 8">
              </app-custom-checkbox>
            </div>
          </div>


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

in html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div *ngIf="condition1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
      <label for="checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="condition2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
      <label for="checkbox2">Checkbox 2</label>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="condition3">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
      <label for="checkbox3">Checkbox 3</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

in css

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid-container div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}


OP clearly asked to use Bootstrap, not plain css.
